# PostgreSQL: How to get parameters in C extension function?

Tags: c, postgresql

I'm writing a C user defined extension function for Postgres and would like to get the value of parameter that I set in SQL level in my C code.

For example, in SQL, I have something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_test_function(text) RETURNS text AS 'path_to_so', 'my_function' LANGUAGE C STRICT SET some_boolean TO true;
```

The question is how can I get the value of **some_boolean** variable in my C code?

```
Datum my_test_function(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {
// try to get some_boolean here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`some_boolean` must be an existing GUC (configuration parameter), else the function definition will produce

```
ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "some_boolean"
```

If it is a GUC, it is either a core PostgreSQL GUG, or it was registered somewhere with `DefineCustomBoolVariable` (from `utils/guc.h`).

Each GUC belongs to a C variable, commonly a global one.

Use that variable in your code!

Comment: Thank @Laurenz Albe. It's registered in _PG_init function.